# Memory Management with UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I wanted to double check that I was doing correct memory management.  Is this correct?  Do I have the correct amount of releases.

In my .h file:

```
UITableView *_sortOrderTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *SortOrderTableView;
```

In my .m file:

In dealloc

```
 [_sortOrderTableView release];
```

My code that presents the popover is this:

```
- (IBAction)sortButtonOrderPressed:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *sortOrderController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.SortOrderTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
self.SortOrderTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"App_Background.png"]];
self.SortOrderTableView.bounces = NO;
self.SortOrderTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    sortOrderController.view = self.SortOrderTableView;
    sortOrderController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 100);
    self.SortOrderTableView.delegate = self;
    self.SortOrderTableView.dataSource = self;

    self.SortPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sortOrderController];
    [self.SortPopover presentPopoverFromRect:_sortButtonOrder.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    [self.SortOrderTableView release];
    [sortOrderController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[self.SortOrderTableView release];`, it should be `[_sortOrderTableView release];` or `self.SortOrderTableView = nil`anyway, but you're already calling that in your dealloc method, so there is no need to release it here. If you want to release it though, use `self.SortOrderTableView = nil`.

Apart from that you will also have to `release` your SortPopover's instance variable in your `dealloc` method.

Comment: why do you use the [_sortOrderTableView release] vs the self.SortOrdersTableView release]?  That part was never clear to me. Thx.

Comment: self.SortOrdersTableView is basically an instance method, created by @synthesize to set and get _sortOrderTableView and you can't release methods. _sortOrderTableView however is an instance variable, which you can (and should) release